# how to redirect to current page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have my index page in which i am directing a link something like this

```
<li onClick="CreateUser()"> <a href="#CreateUser">CreateUser</a>  </li>
```

on click of this create user list item i am populating the main page content as

```
function Create User(){ 
$("#main-content").html('Welcome to user management');
}
```

in my index.html to display some text when user first visit the page ,i have the main-content as

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner" id="main-content">

        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <!--the index dashboard body goes here  -->
            index page content

        </div>
      </div><!-- /.inner -->
    </div><!-- /.outer -->
</div><!-- /#content -->
```

what i want to do is when i refresh when i am on

```
localhost:/example/index.html#CreateUser
```

then it should display the content of CreateUser function

so far , i have tried doing this in index.html page

```
<body onLoad="checkRefresh();">

where "check Refresh()" is 

function check Refresh()
{
var geturl = window.location.href;
if (geturl = 'http://localhost/example/index.html#CreateUser')
$("#main-content").html('Welcome to usermanagment');
}
```

but it directs all other page on refresh to this content

how to do this

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of your `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer i used the window.location.hash and switch case

```
function hash()  
{
//on this function clicking on icons will give the content according to tab
switch(window.location.hash) {



 case "#CreateUser":
 $('#CreateUser').trigger('click',CreateUser());
 break;

 case "#EditUser":
 $('#EditUser').trigger('click',EditUser());
 break;

 case "#DeleteUser":
 $('#DeleteUser').trigger('click',DeleteUser());
 break;  

 default:
 window.location.hash = "";

 break;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use window.location.hash and jQuery ready

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       if(window.location.hash === '#CreateUser')
            $("#main-content").html('Welcome to usermanagment');
    });
```